# sql command to show Time in and Time out from two table of Same dates com paired by Employee code

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
select Tin.TimeIn,Tin.Date,Tout.TimeOut,tout.Date
from AttendanceTimeIn as Tin
Join AttendanceTimeOut as Tout on Tin.Code=tout.Code
where tout.Code=14 and Tin.Date between `('2014-01-22')` and `('2014-01-23')`
```

Its output is:

```
Time in     Date            TimeOut Date
07:31       2014-01-22      04:47   2014-01-22
07:31       2014-01-22      10:46   2014-01-23
10:41       2014-01-23      04:47   2014-01-22
10:41       2014-01-23      10:46   2014-01-23
```

I want records of matching dates only

Comment: it matching employee code of 22.01.2014 date of all the Dates In timeOut table contains same Id plz help me resolve  this prob

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select Tin.TimeIn,Tin.Date,Tout.TimeOut,tout.Date
from AttendanceTimeIn as Tin
Join AttendanceTimeOut as Tout on Tin.Code=tout.Code and Tin.Date = Tout.Date
where tout.Code=14
```

**(OR)**

```
Select Tin.TimeIn,Tin.Date,Tout.TimeOut,tout.Date
from AttendanceTimeIn as Tin
Join AttendanceTimeOut as Tout on Tin.Code=tout.Code and Tin.Date = Tout.Date
where tout.Code=14 AND Tin.Date between `('2014-01-22')` and `('2014-01-23')`
```

Comment: i want dates in between also so i can check the record of in bw dates

Comment: @user3201772 I have updated my answer.please check it now. Mark answer if its helped you

Answer (score 0):

TRY this and I ensures that Time-in are shown even without Time-out

```
SELECT  Tin.TimeIn,
        Tin.Date,
        Tout.TimeOut,
        tout.Date
FROM    AttendanceTimeIn As Tin
        Left Outer Join AttendanceTimeOut As Tout
            On Tin.Code=tout.Code
            And Tin.Date = tout.Date
WHERE   Tout.Code=14
        And Tin.Date Between '2014-01-22' And '2014-01-23'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output is this right?

```
Time in     Date            TimeOut  Date
07:31       2014-01-22      04:47    2014-01-22 
10:41       2014-01-23      10:46    2014-01-23
```

You can simply add a condition on you WHERE clause

```
 WHERE tout.Code=14 and Tin.Date between `('2014-01-22')` and `('2014-01-23')`
  AND (tin.Date = tout.Date);
```